# Why is FF in Kali making requests to ocsp.digicert.com?

Tags: web-browser, kali-linux

Warning -> n00b here!

For some time now I am learning the tools for pen-testing but I am still complete n00b. I have installed Metasplitable2 in another computer on local network and I am running Kali as VM on my computer. So I have started BurpSuite to capture traffic to :8180/admin/ on Metaspoitable2. But to my surprise I saw (apart from the expected traffic) POST requests to ocsp.digicert.com. My Kali installation is default (no new SW installed). So my question is: why is Kali browser making POST requests to ocsp.digicert.com. Is this normal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. ocsp.digicert.com is the server used to verify if an SSL certificate issued by DigiCert got revoked. This is done using the [OCSP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol).

For example the certificates for mozilla.org or addons.mozilla.org are currently issued by DigiCert. This means it will likely check at startup for extension updates and/or browser updates by using HTTPS and will in this context check that the certificates for these domains were not revoked.